# Pip path issue with Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, pip

I have a path issue with pip on Windows 10. I have install the last version of python 3.11 and uninstall the old one 3.9. I managed to link python 3.11 to the variable environnement, however pip is still trying to find the path to python 3.9.

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\Users\{Username}\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe"  "C:\Users\{Username}\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\pip.exe" install pandas': Le fichier spΘcifiΘ est introuvable.
```

I have set the pip.ini with the correct path :

```
target = C:\Users\{Username}\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts\pip.exe
```

But pip keeps pointing to python 3.9.
I have also tried to use pip using python :

```
python -m pip install pandas
```

But I get an error:

```
ERROR: Target path exists but is not a directory, will not continue.
```

From what I understand this error seems to point out the target issue that I have already tried to fix.

Can anyone please help me with this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the path of `python 3.9` from environment variable.

Comment: I did not find the python 3.9 in the environnement variable. I did not delete myself and I don't know if it was done automatically when python 3.9 was uninstalled

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).